# How to call variable outside of it's Scope in processing

Tags: processing

I have been working on a program in Processing that compares two images and gives me the percent match. I am doing this by using a for loop that calls a get() for every pixel in the image. I have to find a way to call a variable that is initialized inside of the for loops outside of the loops. I have browsed several websites that can't seem to give me any good answers, and I was wondering if it is even possible, and if not, if there is some way to work around it. Here is my code:

```
PImage fce1;
PImage fce2;

color f1;
color f2;

void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  background(#353535);
  fce1 = loadImage("Face1.jpg");
  fce2 = loadImage("Face2.jpg.png");
}

void draw(){
  image(fce1, width/2 - 500, 200, 350, 500);
  image(fce2, width/2 + 150, 200, 350, 500);



  //line(width/2 - 150, height/2 - 250, width/2 + 150, height/2 - 250);
  for(int i = height/2 - 250; i <= fce1.height + (height/2 - 250); i ++){
    for(int x = width/2 - 500; x <= fce1.width + (width/2 - 500); x ++){
      color vm1 = fce1.get(x, i);
      this.f1 = vm1;

    }
  }
  for(int i = height/2 - 250; i <= fce2.height + (height/2 - 250); i ++){
    for(int x = width/2 + 150; x <= fce2.width + (width/2 + 150); x ++){
      color vm2 = fce2.get(x, i);
      this.f2 = vm2;
    }
  }


}


void mousePressed(){
  if(mouseX >= 20 && mouseX <= 70 && mouseY >= 20 && mouseY <=70){
    exit();
  }
}
```

I am trying to call the variable f1 outside of the for() loop, since the for() loop initializes it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The `f1` variable is defined at the top of your sketch, so you can use it wherever you want. Also note that the `f1` variable will only "keep" the last value you give it.

Comment: Oh. Thanks then. I'll try that.

Comment: ...what are you trying?

Comment: You gave me an idea that I think will work. I'm going to try it.

Comment: What do you mean by calling variables? You don't call variables, you access/read/modify them usually. You call functions/methods

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it after the for loop since you've created it as a global variable. But your f1 and f2 variables are just going to store the *last* pixel in each image. If you need to compare pixel by pixel, your images would need to have the same pixel count anyway right? So just do the comparisons in your for loop, instead of looping through the whole first image then the whole second one, it'll run faster and actually do what you want I think.